# Track files in a directory automatically

Tags: php, google-analytics, tracking

Is there any way to track simple files in a directory with Google Analytics or PHP using htaccess redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use htaccess to pass all files through a page which includes a Google Analytics script on the file.

This won't work for image file, css, etc.